# md-virtual-repeat refresh and stay in scroll index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a list of md-virtual-repeat.

While scrolling I want to refresh from server.

What i currently do is recreate the list object:

```
$scope.dynamicItems = new DynamicItems();
```

But it takes the list back to top (scroll Index 0).

How can I "refresh" the list (get Viewd pages and clear the rest) and still remain on the same scrolled index?

[Codepan Example](http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/KgdBKx)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Just needed to reset the inner loadedPages.

```
DynamicItems.prototype.reset = function() {
      this.loadedPages = {};
};
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/rrOQkB)